# find text in one column and display in another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a column containing text (column A in Screeshot), which has some tags (text surrounded by < >), I would like to find all these tags in a cell and copy it to the neighbouring cell (Column B in screenshot), basicaly I want to make a list of tags in column A.

Thanks,
Kiran

[image]

Comment: I see you are looking for a code solution - what have you tried so far?

Comment: Agree with @brettdj here. You will have to show what you tried and where are you stuck. BTW here is a hint: you can solve your problem with `RegExp` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a macro that does what exactly what you need.

```
Sub ExtractTags()
Dim ColA As Integer
Dim ColB As Integer
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Content As String
Dim Tags As String
Dim CurrentTag As String
Dim OpenTag As Integer
Dim CloseTag As Integer
Dim NumOfTags As Integer

ColA = 1 'this marks column A
ColB = 2 'this marks column B
Row = 2 'this marks the Row, which we'll increment 1 by 1 to make the code go thru each row

Do
    Content = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, ColA).Value 'extracts the content for manipulation

    If InStr(1, Content, "<", vbBinaryCompare) Then 'This checks to see if there are any tags at all. If there are, we go in
        Position = 0 'this is the starting position of the search
        NumOfTags = 0 'this helps keep track of multiple tags in a single cell

        Do
            'each time this part loops, it cuts out the first tag and all the content before it so that the code can hit the
            'first instance of "<" of the remaining content of the cell
            Position = InStr(Position + 1, Content, "<", vbBinaryCompare) 'finds the first instance of "<"
            NumOfTags = NumOfTags + 1 'since we have a tag, increment the counter by 1

            OpenTag = InStr(Position, Content, "<", vbTextCompare) 'marks the begining of the tag
            CloseTag = InStr(Position, Content, ">", vbTextCompare) - 1 'marks the end of the tag

            CurrentTag = Left(Content, CloseTag) 'cuts out the content after the tag
            CurrentTag = Right(CurrentTag, Len(CurrentTag) - OpenTag) 'cuts out the content before the tag

            If NumOfTags = 1 Then 'this part checks to see if we've already got tags
                Tags = CurrentTag 'if this is the first tag, just put it in
            Else
                Tags = Tags & ", " & CurrentTag 'if this is the second tag onwards, we add a comma to seprate the tags
            End If
        Loop Until InStr(Position + 1, Content, "<", vbBinaryCompare) = False 'this is the checker to see if there are anymore tags in the content

        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, ColB).Value = Tags 'input all the tags into column B
    End If

    Row = Row + 1 'move on to the next row
Loop Until Content = "" 'if the next row is empty, we stop
End Sub
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I worked perfectly thanks Oppoin! I am new to excel-vba, I tried to do this using formulas but dint work, now if the tags are closed by %% instead of <>, can I use your code by replacing all <> with %?

Comment: Hi Kiran, that might not work. My code assumes that the start tag and end tag markers are different, so having both be "%" will make the code not work. If you want, I can modify the code such that it can look for pairs of % signs, but I'll have to get back to you on that later